# Some questions on mocking EF 5 and testing repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I've been reading a bunch of articles on mocking my repository pattern EF 5 and I am confused about a few things:

I have a Manager class, with a method say `AddCat(string name);`. That method ensures the `name` is valid, and calls `AddCat(string name)` on my `CatRepository`. The `CatRepository` just does `myContext.Cats.Add(new Cat() { Name = name });`

That I believe is the repository pattern in a nutshell.

- Should I pass the repository into the Manager class so I can later unit test it, or should I just be testing repositories?
- I want to pass a context into my repository so I can unit test it. So I'd create an interface `IMyContext` but I am not sure how to get the EF context to implement it - as the place I'd add it is in auto-generated code and I worry it would just wipe it. Is there some other way to let me pass in a custom context to the repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I pass the repository into the Manager class so I can later
>   unit test it, or should I just be testing repositories?

You should test each class in isolation. Your Manager class contains actual business logic so you probably want to test a couple of scenarios:

- Valid name
- Invalid name
- Empty name

You want to make sure that `CatRepository.Add` is not called when the name is invalid and that it's called with the correct name when it's valid. To achieve this you make sure that your `Manager` class works with an interface `ICatRepository`. In your unit test you use a technique called [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) to pass a fake implementation of your ICatRepository to your Manager class. The mock has special functionality that lets you check which methods where called and validate the arguments to those methods.

This implies that your Manager should not construct the CatRepository itself:

```
// Not a good solution
public class Manager
{
    public Manager()
    {
        this.catRepository = new CatRepository();
    }
}
```

This way you have no way of replacing the `CatRepository` with your mocked version. Instead you should use a method called Dependency Injection:

```
 // Seperate construction from business logic
 public class Manager
 {
     public Manager(ICatRepository catRepository)
     {
         this.catRepository = catRepository;
     }
 }
```

Your `CatRepository` does not contain any actual logic. You can use integration tests (slower running tests that use a real database or other external object) to make sure that your repositories function correctly.

I wrote a blog about this subject around a year ago that explains the difference between integration and unit tests and how mocking can help you to create good unit tests: [Unit Testing, hell or heaven?](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2012/03/unit-testing-hell-or-heaven.html)

> I want to pass a context into my repository so I can unit test it. So
>   I'd create an interface IMyContext but I am not sure how to get the EF
>   context to implement it - as the place I'd add it is in auto-generated
>   code and I worry it would just wipe it. Is there some other way to let
>   me pass in a custom context to the repository?

Your context is generated as a `partial class`. [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) means that your class can be spread over multiple .cs files. The compiler merges those files together and outputs one single class for it. This way you can have one  .cs file that is autogenerated by EF and another one that implements your interface. Something like this:

*mycontext.cs*

```
public partial class MyContext : ObjectContext
{ }
```

*mycontextinterface.cs*

```
public interface IMyContext {}

public partial class MyContext : IMyContext
{ }
```

Comment: Excellent thank you very much for this reply, it answers all my questions! :)

Comment: Do you know what datatype I should use in my interface? Since MyContext has `public DbSet<Cats> Cats { get; set; }` I don't think I want my interface to use DbSet. IEnumerable would be good, but then it says not implemented. Unless I write a wrapper in my partial class.

Comment: You can expose an IDbSet property. That one is implemented by DbSet.  You definitely don't want to convert all your DbSets to IEnumerable because then you would lose the ability to convert your Linq To Entity queries to SQL and move the work to your database. The DbContext is such a low level object that's only used in integration tests that it makes no sense to further abstract it to 'unit test it'. Microsoft already has unit tests for EF :)